# How can i find out which Library Package it is?

Tags: java, api, interface, google-api, package

i want to write a google api interface

but i have a very basic problem, i have this imports (below) but i dont know which library-file (.jar) belongs to the import. For information its a java programm

```
import com.google.api.ads.common.lib.conf.ConfigurationLoadException;
import com.google.api.ads.common.lib.exception.ValidationException;
import com.google.api.ads.dfa.axis.factory.DfaServices;
import com.google.api.ads.dfa.axis.v1_20.Advertiser;
import com.google.api.ads.dfa.axis.v1_20.AdvertiserRecordSet;
import com.google.api.ads.dfa.axis.v1_20.AdvertiserRemote;
import com.google.api.ads.dfa.axis.v1_20.AdvertiserSearchCriteria;
import com.google.api.ads.dfa.lib.client.DfaSession;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.MemoryDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
```

Answer (score 0):

Name of the JAR file is

```
ads-lib-1.10.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is what you are looking for: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup